# How to get a value jquery from a form in order to .text it in a span without disappearing?

Tags: jquery, html

I can't find why my value is disappearing when I .append it and set it in a var to .text it in a span. The job is to show a form on the click of the button 'label' then set the data in the input:text field in a var and .text it in a span. Try this code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $label, $form, $newForm, $resultat;
    $label = $('.label');
    $form = $('form');
    $newForm = $('#newForm');
    $resultat = $('#resultat');

    $label.on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $newForm.after('Texte du label' + '<form><input type="text" id="itemField" /><input type="submit" id="OK" value="OK"/></form>');
    });

    $('input:submit').live('click', function () {
        var text = $('input:text').val();
        alert($(this).val());
        $resultat.html(text);
    });
```

and the html is

```
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      #gauche {
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
        padding : 10px;
        height: 850px;
        background-color: #EFECCA;
      }
      #droite {
        background-color: #CEFFF8;
        height: 850px;
        padding : 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding-left: 71%;
      }
      p {
        display: inline-block;    
      }
      #resultat {
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      #newForm {
        display: inline-block;    
      }
      footer {
        padding: 20px auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .social {
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: black;
        width:360px;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .copyright {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        padding: 0px 0 20px;
        margin: 1px 40%;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .social a {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
      }

      a .link-color {
        color: black;
      }

      .social span {
        margin: 0 5%;
        line-height: 1;
        color: black;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="gauche">
        <span id="resultat"></span>
    </section>
    <aside id="droite">
      <h3>Utilisez ces boutons pour créer votre formulaire</h3><br><br>
      <button class='label'>Label</button>
      <button class='zone'>Zone de texte</button>
      <button class='bouton'>Bouton</button>
      <hr>
      <div id="newForm"></div>

    </aside>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are attaching an event to something that doesn't yet exist.  therefore jquery won't attach it properly.  You have to use event delegation on either the parent or something higher. you can set the click event on the body, which will always exist.

The live event has been deprecated from jQuery 1.7 onwards so you should use on

```
$('body').on('click', 'input:submit', function(){....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work. I have put an event on the body like you said but it's activated the script for each click. And even on the span where the text should be settled, it disapeared also... My event on click is on the button label. When i click a form appears. From this form i set the input:text value in a var text, and then .html() it or .text() it in my span. But it appears only a second. Why is it hapening?

Comment: Sorry, i've just edited it.  I missed the the comma separation in event.  try it with that implementation

Comment: It worked, but it disappeared, as my function... So i've inspected and installed a reseter.css, but i can't find why the text don't stay... he should be not at ease there... well have tried my code with style and stuff? does it work for you?

Comment: you will also have to prevent the form from submitting if you want to see the value on submit.  Otherwise it will post the page, which is why you're seeing the value disappear.

Comment: add `$('body').on('click', 'input:submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); //your code };`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i understood why it disappearde, so i've prevent it. You rocks thank you Branny ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your this portion of code with the below one

From this

```
$('input:submit').live('click', function () {
    var text = $('input:text').val();
    alert($(this).val());
    $resultat.html(text);
});
```

to

```
 $('input:submit').live('click', function (event) {
event.prevetDefault();
       var text = $('input:text').val();
       alert($(this).val());
       $resultat.html(text);
    });
```